# How to release a struct that wasn't called with malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Assume I have a struct `node` like such:

```
struct node {
   struct other_struct value;
   int some_num;
}
```

I have seen snippets of code where the struct can be initialized without calling `malloc`, like this:

```
struct node my_node;
my_node.value = NULL;
my_node.some_num = 2;
```

And then `value` can later be malloced. However, how would I free `my_node`?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile

Comment: You can't free it. And you actually don't need to. If it is a local variable the compiler will take care of managing that memory. If it is a static or global variable then it remains valid for the entire code execution and its memory will never need to be reclaimed whilst the process is running.

Comment: If value is a pointer you want to `malloc` (I don't exactly get your question), `my_node` wouldn't have to be freed even if you `malloc` `value`. However, you might have to free `value`.

Comment: Possibly you mean `my_node.value = NULL; my_node.some_num = 2;` instead of using the `->` operators there?

Comment: You have to know which memory was allocated via `malloc()` and friends so that you can free it accurately.  If you fix the code and later allocate a `struct other_struct` to be used via `my_node->value`, then you'll need to free that pointer.  You won't need to free `my_node`; it wasn't allocated by `malloc()` and must not be freed.

Comment: I see. However, would I have to `malloc()` and then `free()` the `value` since it's a struct? Or is that taken care of since the parent `my_node` is a local variable?

Answer (score 2):

`my_node` is allocated on the stack, and once it goes out of scope, its memory is automatically deallocated.

Use `malloc` if you want to allocate something on the heap, and it will persist until you free it. For your example, you would do:

```
struct node *my_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
my_node->some_num = 2;
// Sometime later

free(my_node);
```

Space will also be allocated for the `value` field if you malloc (as long as you pass the right size) or if you declare on the stack. `sizeof(struct node)` includes the size of `other_struct`.

Comment: What about the properties of `my_node` that need to be allocated (namely `value`)? Does it also get allocated automatically?

Comment: Yes, even when you do a malloc. Just pass the right size if you ```malloc```. If ```value``` was a pointer to ```other_struct```, then you'd have to allocate it.

Comment: The memory of an automatic object is released when its lifetime ends, not when it goes out of scope. For example, if the address of the object is passed to a subroutine, the subroutine can use the object; it exists, and its memory remains reserved in the subroutine, even though the name of the object is not in scope in the subroutine. The lifetime of an automatic object when execution of its associated block ends (as when a function returns). Lifetime is **when** during program execution an **object** exists. Scope is **where** in source code an **identifier** is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Currently with those code snippets you can't really free value or my_node, as they're both just static variables, if in your node structure, the other_struct field was a pointer, then you could dynamically allocate some memory, and save the address in that pointer.
Then when done, free the pointer value.
If then, my_node was also a pointer (which I think is what you want), you would need to allocate memory for the node struct, and save the address to the pointer my_node. THEN, allocate some memory for the other_struct struct and save it to the pointer value. And after you're done, you would free value FIRST, then free my_node.

When doing things like this, I generally create a little constructor/destructor function, which will do it all for me. It can be too easy to forget to free the inner pointer (value) and just free the outer pointer (mynode). Then that would cause a memory-leak, as value would still be allocated and taking up room in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
struct node {
   struct other_struct value;
   int some_num;
};
```

defines `value` to be a member of `struct node`. It is a part of `struct node`. Whenever a `struct node` is created, it will contain the member named `value`, and no other memory needs to be allocated for `value`. Whether a `struct node` is created automatically or by `malloc` or other means, its memory will always include memory for `value`.

If you changed it to:

```
struct node {
   struct other_struct *value;
   int some_num;
}
```

then `value` would be a pointer to a `struct other_struct`, and you would need to provide memory for it to point to.

In this code:

```
struct node my_node;
my_node.value = NULL;
my_node.some_num = 2;
```

the object `my_node` is created automatically, and you do not have to do anything to release it or its members; that will happen automatically. You cannot use `my_node.value = NULL` because `value` is a structure, not a pointer.

If the structure definition is changed so that `value` is a pointer, then you can set to `NULL`, or you can set it to point at an existing object, or you can allocate memory for it and set it to point to the allocated memory. If you allocate memory for it, then you should ensure that memory is later freed (except it is okay not to free it if you are intentionally keeping it to the end of program execution anyway, and you are executing in user mode on a general-purpose operating system).

Answer (score 0):

You don't free it... it is destroyed, when the block it has been declared in is abandoned by the program.

Let's say that this variable is defined at the beginning of a function's body block.  When the function is being called, the function creates this variable as it's a local.  When the function terminates, all local variables are destroyed, so it is your local structure.

If you declare such a variable out of any function, then your variable has global duration, and it is created at program initialization, and lives as much as the program itself.